# camel is reading the file continuously

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am working with apache camel, In my application there are many components, In first Component I have read the file using apache-camel, and then I have done some processing over this file and after processing of the file, my reporting Logic runs the whole thing runs fine in sunny day scenerio, problem occurs when my reporting is not able to mail due to some template missing then camel again reads that file, that should not be the case, so I would like to stop the camel to read the file, so the camel read the file only once not again and again..................

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `idempotent` option in the file component. This feature will remember the files that you have already consumed. You can remember the files based on the `idempotentKey` using the `File Language` that Camel provides.

Be aware that it will just remember 1000 files by default, if you need more, you will have to modify the default.

See more info here: [Apache Camel: File2 Component](https://camel.apache.org/file2.html)

Comment: it is working but it is deleting the file, I would like to move that file If it get processed, I have tried move and moveFailed options but not able to move this file